# How to skip/ignore string list element?

Tags: python, list

I'm doing exercises, and I have a problem in one of them.

I have a print the smallest, and the highest number in a list. When the program sees a string, it has to ignore it. I don't know how to do it.

```
def find_hi_lo(list):
    return(min(list), max(list))

a = find_hi_lo([10, 2, 3, 4, 6])
print(a)

(2, 10)

a = find_hi_lo([10, 2, 3, 'aaa', 4, 6])
print(a)
```

Gives the error:

```
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Avoid using `list` as a variable name, it is normally a Python function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `filter` out all the undesired elements first.

```
from numbers import Number

def find_hi_lo(list0):
    temp = list(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, Number), list0))
    return(min(temp), max(temp))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a list comprehension to filter out the non-numeric values

```
def find_hi_lo(data):
    data = [i for i in data if isinstance(i, float) or isinstance(i, int)]
    return min(data), max(data)

>>> find_hi_lo([10, 2, 3, 'aaa', 4, 6])
(2, 10)
```

Answer (score 2):

Lists can contain values of arbitrary types, but they work best when you restrict them to values of the same type (or, at least, values supporting any protocol expected by the consumer). In this case, both `min` and `max` expect values that are comparable to each other. The easiest thing to do here is to filter the strings out *before* you pass the list to `find_hi_lo`. Ideally, you would do this by not adding strings to the list in the first place, but you can remove them on demand like so:

```
find_hi_lo([x for x in [10, 2, 3, 'aaa', 4, 6] if not isinstance(x, str)])
```